# NullPointerException in ImageMosaic Preview

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic

**Description:**

I am encountering a `NullPointerException` when attempting to preview an ImageMosaic layer at a zoomed-out level. Interestingly, the issue does not occur during WMS requests.

**Environment:**

- Geoserver v2.24.1
- OSGeo docker
- Extensions - importer,wps,ysld,gdal,wps-download,wmts-multi-dimensional,css,gwc-s3,sldservice,feature-pregeneralized,monitor, cog

**Debugging process:**

- Recreated image mosaic store. [Didn't help]
- Created a copy imagemosaic layer with same properties and source files on local geoserver deployment (built from source code). The problem did not occur there.
- Attempted to debug the actual GeoServer instance with remote JVM debugging but couldn't pinpoint the origin of the problem due to limited familiarity with the source codes.
- Issue isn't in source files, as in local geoserver instance the same files are used and the issue isn't occurring there.

**Stack Trace:**

> ```
> 14 004 14:04:29 ERROR  [geoserver.ows] - 
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2110)
>   at javax.media.jai.PlanarImage.getData(PlanarImage.java:2016)
>   at javax.media.jai.RenderedOp.getData(RenderedOp.java:2266)
>   at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageTimeDecorator.getData(RenderedImageTimeDecorator.java:129)
>   at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.png.ScanlineProviderFactory.getProvider(ScanlineProviderFactory.java:54)
>   at it.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.png.PNGWriter.isScanlineSupported(PNGWriter.java:128)
>   at org.geoserver.wms.map.png.PNGJWriter.writePNG(PNGJWriter.java:34)
>   at org.geoserver.wms.map.PNGMapResponse.formatImageOutputStream(PNGMapResponse.java:101)
>   at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapResponse.write(RenderedImageMapResponse.java:110)
>   at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.response(Dispatcher.java:1018)
>   at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:272)
>   at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177)
> ...
> ```

How can I identify the root cause of the NullPointerException?

Comment: If it doesn't occur in a local build with no extensions then you need to add the extensions in one at a time to see which one causes the issue. Or see. If a local build works in the container?

Comment: I tested with all the extensions added as well, and it doesn't occur in the local instance. My guess is that it is a configuration issue, but don't know where to start searching from as the exception doesn't say anything specific.

Comment: Turn the logging level up and try again